# is there a way to accept non blocking command line input in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to accept multiple command line inputs in rust. The user hits enter to and gets a response on the input. Along with this, I also want to close the client if user hits `ctrl+c` while entering the response. I am struggling to achieve this in my solution.

I am using `tokio::select` for this purpose with 2 branches responsible for accepting `ctrl+c` and user input. Using `tokio::signal` to capture the `ctrl+c` keystroke.

```rust
use mio::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::signal;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let shutdown = signal::ctrl_c();

    tokio::select! {
        _ = shutdown => {
            println!("after shutdown");
        }
        res = accept_input() => {
            println!(".."); // this will never run due to infinite loop in accept_input()
        }
    }
}

pub async fn accept_input() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    loop {
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        let word = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `read_line()` is a blocking function and hence the `shutdown` branch listening to `ctrl+c` doesn't get the thread execution to capture `tokio::signal::ctrl_c()` signal.

An alternative implementation, where the responsibility of the `accept_input()` function was to listen on a `TcpListener` for new incoming socket connections with the help of `await` keyword, gives the desired results. Since `await` definition states it `Suspend execution until the result of a [Future] is ready.` Hence, the `shutdown` branch in `tokio::select` gets execution after the first `.await` on `TcpListener`.

Here is the code which gives desired result.

```rust
pub async fn accept_input() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8000").await?;
    loop {
        let (client, _) = listener.accept().await?;
    }
}
```

I am struggling to come up with a way to achieve the same in case of accepting command line inputs. As I understand, new incoming socket connections can be thought of as new incoming command line message.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`tokio::io::stdin`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/fn.stdin.html).

Comment: I just realized that this is basically aslo doing blocking reads, but on a different thread, so I'm really not sure this is actually what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to read commandline input from the user in an interactive manner, the async facilities in Tokio are not what you are looking for. The `tokio::io::stdin` method admits this in its documentation:

> This handle is best used for non-interactive uses, such as when a file is piped into the application. For technical reasons, stdin is implemented by using an ordinary blocking read on a separate thread, and it is impossible to cancel that read. This can make shutdown of the runtime hang until the user presses enter.
>
> For interactive uses, it is recommended to spawn a thread dedicated to user input and use blocking IO directly in that thread.

To do this, you can use a utility like the one below:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

struct InteractiveStdin {
    chan: mpsc::Receiver<std::io::Result<String>>,
}

impl InteractiveStdin {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let (send, recv) = mpsc::channel(16);
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            for line in std::io::stdin().lines() {
                if send.blocking_send(line).is_err() {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        InteractiveStdin {
            chan: recv
        }
    }
    
    /// Get the next line from stdin.
    ///
    /// Returns `Ok(None)` if stdin has been closed.
    ///
    /// This method is cancel safe.
    async fn next_line(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<Option<String>> {
        self.chan.recv().await.transpose()
    }
}
```

By using `std::thread::spawn` rather than `tokio::task::spawn_blocking`, the Tokio runtime will *not* wait for the thread before shutting down. This is important as it may be waiting for user input indefinitely.

Using the above code with `tokio::signal` looks like this:

```
use tokio::signal;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let shutdown = signal::ctrl_c();
    
    let mut stdin = InteractiveStdin::new();

    tokio::select! {
        _ = shutdown => {
            println!("after shutdown");
        }
        res = stdin.next_line() => {
            println!("got line: {:?}", res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Just an issue I came across, `use of unstable library feature 'stdin_forwarders'
see issue #87096 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87096>` The workaround for it is `std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut buf)` where `buf` is `String::new()` and this goes in a `loop {}` for reading lines.

Comment: The method I used was stabilized in 1.62.0, so that error is because your compiler is older than that.

Comment: Definitely, It's is because of that.